# jruby activerecord-jdbc-adapter connection pool is not reconnecting after socketTimeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, jruby, activerecord-jdbc

I am using jruby and mysql2 gem version mysql2 (0.3.11).
My database.yml looks something like this.

```
production:

  <<: *common
  database: database
  host: host
  port: 3306
  username: username
  password: ********
  pool: 5
  pool_initial: true
  checkout_timeout: 0.3
     properties:
     connectTimeout: 250
     socketTimeout: 90000
```

One of the queries exceeded socket timeout of 90 seconds in my case and after that, each of the requests that are using same connection from the pool started failing. I am expecting mysql2 should reconnect but It is not reconnecting in my case. I looked at the documentation but could not find anything.

Edit1: I did little bit of more debuging and I am using [activerecord-jdbc-adapter](https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/) in production instead of mysql2 gem and I tried fixing the problem using autoReconnect: true but looks like it is not recommended as it can mess up with consistency. 
http://pages.citebite.com/p4x3a0r8pmhm

Edit2: Version - jruby(1.7.4) and activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.9.1)

Comment: Have you tried to add `reconnect: true` option in your `database.yml`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried autoReconnect: true but Looks like it is not recommended.
http://pages.citebite.com/p4x3a0r8pmhm

Answer (score -1):

first of all if you're under JRuby you can not be using mysql2 gem.

you're using a JDBC driver (jdbc-mysql gem - you identified that correctly).

`reconnect: true` should have worked (maps to `autoReconnect: true` property), without the reconnect AR's pool likely doesn't detect an invalid connection properly. this might actually depend from Rails version to version and might also be considered a activerecord-jdbc-adapter bug.

Comment: I am using jruby-1.7.4, do you know if it is a bug? I could not find any bug reported to activerecord-jdbc-adapter repository.